# Are there any atelic ditransitive verbs (or verb phrases)?

Tags: syntax, semantics, verbs, aspect, aktionsart

I am wondering if there are any verbs/phrases that qualify *both* as ditransitive, *and* as atelic. The following shows the relevant tests. The satisfying verb/phrase should have the same * patterns as *give* w.r.t. ditransitivity, but * patterns with *sleep* and *watch* in the telicity tests. A complete answer will provide the evidence that the proposed word passes the test in these ways.

(*'s in the below indicate low acceptability. Note that the absence of a phrase must be interpreted as the absence of *any* inferrable phrase--adding a phrase silently will increase acceptability, but this should be avoided in order to understand the judgments. It is also intended that a difference in transitivity not change the meaning of the verb, so sometimes a * might indicate that example is not interpretable in the same way as the corresponding non-*ed examples.)

**Intransitive**:

> Al slept.
>
> *Al watched.
>
> *Al gave.

**Transitive**:

> *Al slept a man.
>
> Al watched TV.
>
> *Al gave a ring.

**Ditransitive**:

> *Al watched Mary TV.
>
> *Al watched TV to Mary.
>
> Al gave Mary a ring.
>
> Al gave a ring to Mary.

**Single-event compatibility with "in"-phrases**:

> *Al slept in an hour.
>
> *Al watched TV in an hour.
>
> Al gave Mary a ring in a year.

**Single event compatibility with "for"-adverbials**:

> Al slept for an hour.
>
> Al watched TV for an hour.
>
> *Al gave Mary a ring for a year.

**Entailment from the progressive to the perfect**:

> Al is sleeping. => Al has slept.
>
> Al is watching TV. => Al has watched TV.
>
> Al is giving Mary a ring. !=> Al has given Mary a ring.

**Single-event compatibility with "a lot"**:

> Al slept a lot last night.
>
> Al watched TV a lot last night.
>
> *Al gave Mary a ring a lot last night.

Comment: Am I right or if you replace "a ring" by "rings", "to give" is going to pass every tests?

Comment: Bare plural nouns ("rings") make a verbal phrase atelic.

Comment: I would like to distinguish atelic in the sense of "durative" from the sense of "frequentative". Hence some tests explicitly mentioned "single-event compatibility": with "for"-phrases, you get a multiple event interpretation: _Al gave Mary rings for a year_, similarly with "a lot": _Al gave Mary rings a lot last night_. You also don't get the entailment from the progressive: _Al is giving Mary rings_ !=> _Al has given Mary rings_.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possibilities, I guess it depends on your test of telicity. In English telicity depends to a large degree on the semantics of the arguments.

rent; allow; cause; cost; guarantee; leave; owe.

Comment: I'm going to update the question so that its clear the tests should be applied for a complete answer. Using arguments like those in the tests I listed, each of these items fails to pass one or more tests. "rent" is the best, but I think even it fails the single event with "a lot" test, if not also the progressive entailment to the simple past.

Comment: @AlexisWellwood I did think through the tests with each, and felt they passed (of course, introspection is an unreliable guide to grammaticality) but am quite willing to accept I was wrong on some. But to reiterate, I think their acceptability depends a lot on the arguments. Also I should have made clear *leave* is not the motion verb but inheritance.